# Thieves in caves coding puzzle

Tags: algorithm

My friend shared this coding puzzle with me and I'm stuck. Here's the puzzle:

> Imagine an array of caves and a thief, where caves are represented by
>   array index. Every day, the thief can move one cave in either
>   direction and can return to previously visited caves, but he must make
>   a move and no wrap-around is allowed.
>
> You are given a list of caves to check, one per day in chronological
>   order. Return whether or not those moves guarantees you will catch the
>   thief in at least one of your checks.

What I've come up with:

> Assume the caves array is 0-indexed. Then, you can define "boundary"
>   points as indexes 1 and len(caves) - 2. As long as you start at a
>   boundary point, linearly sweep to the next boundary point, re-check a
>   boundary point the next day after you've reached one, and then sweep
>   back to the other boundary point, you are guaranteed to catch the
>   thief. For instance, if our caves is length 5:
>
> 123321 and 123123 would both guarantee the thief is caught.

However, I do not think this is an exhaustive template and there might be different schemes that still work. I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an algorithmic solution to a puzzle, not about a code problem.

Comment: I disagree. This is an algorithm oriented question, and the OP is asking about the algorithm to solve it. Algorithm questions are very much on topic.

Comment: @TopologicalSort no. What if the thief just goes back and forth from 1 to 0, starting at cave 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to solve it is by defining an array of feasible locations for the thief to be without being captured for every step `i`, as follows:

```
Stop clauses and boundaries:
thief[-1][i] = true (for all i in [0,NUM_CAVES))
thief[k][-1] = false (for all k)
thief[k][NUM_CAVES] = false (for all k)
Step:
thief[k][i] = check[k] != i && (thief[k-1][i-1] || thief[k-1][i+1])
```

**Intuition:**

At step `k`, the thief cannot be (without being caught) in cave that is being searched (This is the `check[k] != i` part).

In addition, he cannot be in cave `i`, if it was infeasible for him to be at any adjacent cave at the previous round (which is the second part, `thief[k-1][i-1] || thief[k-1][i+1]`).

This can be solved with [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in `O(n*m)` time, where `n` is the number of caves and `m` is the length of the provided list.

When you finish calculating the table, the answer is basically:

```
NOT(thief[m][0] || thief[m][1] || ... || thief[m][n-1])
```

Which means, the thief cannot be in any cave, assuming he was not caught.

Comment: This is really clever! Of course you should use DP, I was just too stuck trying to find a rigid template. Thanks!

Comment: @amit I am just curious, the assumption that the theif cant be in any cave adjacent to where he previously was how can that hold true? What does theif[i][k] represent?

Comment: `theif[k][i]` represents if it is possible to be at cave `k`, at the `i`th iteration, after the search party checked the cave, and before he jumped to the next cave.